# Is there any library to get audio data in vorbis format with AVCaptureSession in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, webm, vorbis

I have captured the video frames and converted them into VP8 data using the following code : 
https://github.com/chris838/vp8-ios.git

I want to capture vorbis audio data according to the VP8 data that is available to me in order to combine the VP8 data and vorbis data to WebM file. Is there any available iOS Library for fetching the Vorbis Data ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's [ogg](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/08/07/precompiled-ogg-vorbis-libraries-for-ios/) or you may find [audiolib](https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/audiolib.js) helpful. there is a link to the ogg source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/play-ogg-vorbis-ios/source/browse/trunk/Tremor/vorbisfile.c?r=3)